# Filling tx3 TagCloud with ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, tag-cloud

I'm using the tx3 Tag Cloud to visualize some data. 
Actually it is simple to use.

```
<ul id="tagcloud">
<li data-weight="50"><a href="#">HTML5</a></li>
<li data-weight="24"><a href="#">CSS3</a></li>
<li data-weight="28"><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
<li data-weight="32"><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
...
</ul>
```

I want to fill this elements from a list of angular scope with ngRepeat.

```
<li data-weight="{{element.weight}}" ng-repeat="element in list">{{element.title}}</li>
```

In DevTools/Firebug i can see that all li-elements are created but the data-weights are ignored. Without ngRepeat i can see that the style attribute with a size value will be added to the li element. With ngRepeat this is not the case.

I think the problem is that the angular scope is not loaded/initialized at the time when the tag cloud is created. Is there a way to force that the scope is fully loaded before the page load?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with adding a directive to the ng-repeat. In this directive i call the timeout function and initialize the tag cloud after that.

```
function ngRepeatDoneNotification($timeout) {

        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                if (scope.$last){ // ISSUE IS HERE
                        $timeout(function() {
                        $("#tagcloud").tx3TagCloud({
                            multiplier: 5 // default multiplier is "1"
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```